# Align text in a while loop

Tags: php, html, css

How do I align text that is generated in a while loop

Example:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){


echo "<strong>E1:</strong>".$row['Ex1']."<br>";
echo "<strong>E2:</strong> ".$row['Ex2']."<br>";
echo "<strong>E3:</strong> ".$row['Ex3']."<br>";
echo "<strong>E4:</strong> ".$row['Ex4']."<br>";
echo "<strong>E5:</strong> ".$row['Ex5']."<br>";
echo "<strong>E6:</strong> ".$row['Ex6']."<br>";
}
```

Now the alignment is not good I want E1 on the left and the outcome (Ex1/6) aligned on the right

Comment: be more specific, what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "<strong style='float:left;'>E1</strong>
      <span style:float:right;'>.$row['Ex1']."</span><br>";`
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP is server scripting,so, just echo, whatever markup u need markup.....

```
 echo "<span style='float:left'><strong>E1:</strong>
</span><span style='float:right'>".$row['Ex1']."</span><br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
Add style in inline itself

```
echo "<span style='float:left'><strong>E1:</strong>
</span><span style='float:right'>".$row['Ex1']."</span><br>";
```